# copy of magento shop does not look good

Tags: magento-1.9

I copied my magento shop to an other domain and host.

Just downloaded the db and uploaded it in the new db.
copied all files in public html to new public html.

changed db credentials in local.xml and in the db changed core config to the correct secure and unsecure url.

But now the site on the new url looks like this:
www.cbd24.nl and it should look like this: www.mediaboxshop.nl

How to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't reach the website on that domain. Maybe it's a permissions issue. Also, check in the developer tools in Chrome if your CSS en JS files are being loaded. If not, they should be displayed in red in your console.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have refreshed/cleared all Magento caches in admin as well as deleting any cached files that are referencing the old url.

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/session/*
rm -rf media/css*
rm -rf media/js*
```

Comment: @bramvds Please keep your comments in English.

Answer (score 0):

Only deleting the .htaccess in the media folder did the trick. Don't know why.